# Arranging people in groups at a conference

Tags: mathematics

54 people attend a conference. 
There are 6 tables that each seat 9 people. 
Each table has a different topic and all 54 people have to move around and sit at each table. 
Can you advise a formula as to how to move everyone numbered from 1-54 to different tables in a way that each person meets as many other people as possible.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: this is more a mathematical problem rather than a puzzle.)

As a first approximation, the algorithm can be seen as follows (it can be not optimal though):

> Since after each rearrangement, each of the 9 people on a table must occupy a seat at one of the 5 remaining tables, the best way for them to allow meeting more new people is that the one of them goes to the next table (1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 1 etc.), and the other 8 people group in pairs for other 4 tables. E.g.
>  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
>  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
>  19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
>  28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
>  37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
>  46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54
>  will rotate to
>  
> 17 18 24 25 31 32 38 39 46
> 01 26 27 33 34 40 41 47 48
> 02 03 10 35 36 42 43 49 50
> 04 05 11 12 19 44 45 51 52
> 06 07 13 14 20 21 28 53 54
> 08 09 15 16 22 23 29 30 37
>  The same algorithm can be repeated for the next iteration, however one should watch to break the pairs moving from one table to another (i.e. 2 and 3 moved from table 1 to 3, and on the next iteration they should move to different unvisited tables, for example 4 and 5)